# What do these expressions represent in unix?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh

```
  # The **variable slicing** notation in the following conditional
  # needs some explanation: `${var#expr}` returns everything after
  # the match for 'expr' in the variable value (if any), and
  # `${var%expr}` returns everything that doesn't match (in this
  # case, just the very first character. You can also do this in
  # Bash with `${var:0:1}`, and you could use cut too: `cut -c1`.
```

what does this actually means?
can i get an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash

message="hello world!"
var1="hello"
var2="world!"
echo "${message#$var1}"
echo "${message%$var2}"
echo "${message%???}"
echo "${message}"
```

Output:

```
 world!
hello 
hello wor
hello world!
```

Answer (score 1):

The explanation you quoted is not at all accurate. This mechanism allows you to remove a prefix or a suffix from a variable's value.

```
vnix$ v=foobar
vnix$ echo "${v#foo}"
bar
vnix$ echo "${v%bar}"
foo
```

The expression can be a glob, so you are not restricted to static strings.

```
vnix$ echo "${v%b*}"
foo
```

There's also ## and %% to trim the longest match instead of the shortest.

Answer (score 1):

The text quoted in the question is a terrible explanation.  Here is the text from [the sh language standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

```
${parameter%word}
    Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce a pattern.
    The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter, with the smallest portion
    of the suffix matched by the pattern deleted.
${parameter%%word}
    Remove Largest Suffix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce a pattern. 
    The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter, with the largest portion
    of the suffix matched by the pattern deleted.
${parameter#word}
    Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce a pattern.
    The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter, with the smallest portion
    of the prefix matched by the pattern deleted.
${parameter##word}
    Remove Largest Prefix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce a pattern.
    The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter, with the largest portion
    of the prefix matched by the pattern deleted.
```